# Error while publishing Provider-Hosted MVC App to catalog site

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, visual-studio, sharepoint-addin, iis

I am tying to publish SharePoint 2013 Provider-Hosted MVC App to my site. I am getting this error message:

> Parser Error Message: Could not load type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.ListMenu'.

```
Line 7:          <!-- Adapter -->
Line 8:          <controlAdapters>
Line 9:              <adapter controlType="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.ListMenu"
Line 10:                      adapterType="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.ListMenuAdapter" />
Line 11:             <adapter controlType="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.XsltListViewWebPart, Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=#########" 

Source File: C:\inetpub\wwwroot\wss\VirtualDirectories\8080\App_Browsers\compat.browser    Line: 9
```

I checked the compat.browser file but could not get any idea. Do I need to update something in my app manifest file? I am using Visual Studio 2013. Please help.

Answer (score -1):

you mvc applications web.config would have replaced the sharepoint web.config.